# What to use insread of Underscore.js ._where() for the arrays of property values

Tags: underscore.js

Let's say we have the following data:

```
[
 {
      "name": "Experiment type10",
      "scale": ["Whole Brain", "Cell"],
      "datatype": "table"
 },
 {
     "name": "Experiment type11",
     "scale": ["Tissue", "Cell"],
     "datatype": "image"
 },
 {
     "name": "Experiment type12",
     "scale": "Tissue",
     "datatype": "text"
 }
]
```

With Underscore `._where` I can filter out the objects with datatype "text", but I can't  filter out all the objects with scale equals to "Tissue" since it's in an array. Is that possible to do this type of filtering elegantly?

Comment: Are you looking to check `datatype` and `scale` at the same time or just `scale`?

Comment: Why is the `scale` only sometimes an array?

Comment: @Bergi that is unfortunately a given.

Comment: @muistooshort the whole thing is for faceted search, so I'm looking for checking everything possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) and [contains](http://underscorejs.org/#contains):

```
    var hasTissues = function(item){
        return item.scale === 'Tissue' || _.contains(item.scale, 'Tissue');
    }

    var tissues = _.filter(list, hasTissues);
```

Comment: You missed the `datatype` condition. Or maybe I'm reading the question wrong.

Comment: My interpretation was that the OP was suggesting that filtering on the datatype was not a problem but filtering on the scale was causing an issue.

Answer (score 2):

`_.where` is just a shortcut for the general purpose [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter). `_.filter` uses a predicate function rather than a simple list of properties:

```
_(array).filter(function(h) {
    if(h.datatype !== 'text')
        return false;
    if(_(h.scale).isArray())
        return _(h.scale).indexOf('Tissue') !== -1;
    return h.scale === 'Tissue';
});
```

There are various ways of checking to see if `h.scale` is or contains `'Tissue'`: you could use a simple `for`-loop instead of `_.indexOf`, you could use `typeof` instead of `_.isArray`, you could say `a = _([ h.scale ]).flatten()` and check the array `a`, ...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/umwf348k/

Comment: thanks, I've forgotten about `indexOf`. Now it looks a lot shorter